# Winapi StartDoc cannot detect user chose cancel in saveas dialog

Tags: pdf, winapi, printing

When the user responds to the Print dialog invoked by **StartDoc**() function, by pressing **Cancel** button, **StartDoc**() returns false and the program cancels the print job.

However, when the user chooses pdf printer driver, it can open another dialog for naming the pdf file. If the user chooses Cancel at this stage, **StartDoc**() does not return false to the calling function. The program actually performs all the printing process except a file is not created.
How to detect the user selected **Cancel** in **Saveas** dialogbox of the printer driver in order to avoid lengthy printing process.

Is there a way to detect the user selected **Cancel** in the later **Saveas** dialog.

Below is a sample code:

```
  PRINTDLGEX Printdlgex ;

  HDC  PrintDC = GetPrinterDC (hwnd,&Printdlgex) ;

  if  (! PrintDC)
      return false ;

  static DOCINFO di = { sizeof (DOCINFO), "My Program", NULL } ;

  if  (StartDoc (PrintDC,&di) > 0)  {

      if  (StartPage (PrintDC) > 0)  {

          // Lengthy Printing process

      } /* if  (StartPage (PrintDC) > 0) */

  } /* if  (StartDoc (PrintDC,&di) > 0) */
```

Comment: Microsoft has PDF writer for some versions of Windows. Otherwise this is third party software question. Remove `static` keyword. Write a code which will reproducible this behavior.

Comment: I agree that `static` should be removed from the declaration of `di`. Use a new `DOCINFO` instance for each print job. On the other hand, this also sounds like a possible bug in the PDF driver you are using.  If the user cancels setup of the output, I would expect the driver to fail so `StartDoc()` can then fail. If that is not happening, is it possible that the driver is actually writing the output to a temp file?  Try using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see if any files are being created while your app is printing.

Comment: I use static for performance. di never change whether I print to same or different printer. Why make new assign each call to print function?

Comment: It seems Remy is right about pdf driver bug. I tried to print a long Word file in MS Word and WordPad and selected Cancel in save as dialog for both cases. Both MS Word and WordPad did not detect I pressed Cancel button and kept counting pages being printed till end of file. Of coarse no pdf files were created but it took time before return from print job. This bug exists in two different pdf drivers...strange

Comment: There is no performance gain from using `static`, not here anyway

Comment: Without static, the value is assigned to the variable during run time. static allows the value to be assigned to the variable during compilation. The program does not pass on this line during run time.  I am using Visual Studio 2008. I wonder whether other compilers behave differently.